# Pass object from .aspx file to JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

can I somehow pass an objet from my index.aspx to a JavaScript function?

in index:

```
    <% 
    if (Model.ImportedConfig != null)
    {%>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            LoadImportedConfig(Model.ImportedConfig);
        </script>
    <%
    }
    %>
```

JavaScript:

```
    function LoadImportedConfig(config){

        var appId = config.AppId;
        //etc
    }
```

Best regards  Johan

Answer (score 0):

if it was string in could be something like LoadImportedConfig(<%=Model.ImportedConfig%>); but i don't see any another way instead pass this object through ajax+json. When you need this config, just get it from backend by ajax.

but no, wait. Just use json format in incoming parameter. without any ajax